# Compiler does not recognize architecture

Tags: ubuntu, compile

I am having problems compiling a library (XSB Prolog) in Ubuntu.

I am configuring and compiling it with:

```
sudo ./configure -prefix=/usr/local/lib/
sudo ./makexsb
```

Then, I need to execute the following command in order to generate certain dynamic libraries:

```
sudo ./makexsb dynmodule
```

But it is failing with the following output:

```
make -f ../config/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/topMakefile dynmodule

Preparing...
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/parallels/prologengines/XSB/emu'
Making XSB Shared Library /home/parallels/prologengines/XSB/config/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/libxsb.so
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-faltivec’
make[1]: *** [xsbdynmod] Error 1
```

As far as I undestand, the `-faltivec` option only makes sense when building on PowerPC architectures. 
So it might be that the correct architecture is not being detected? If that is the case, how can I be sure that the architecture is detected correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `build/emuMakefile.in`, which produces `config/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/emuMakefile` when running `configure` script, the `-faltivec` flag is hardcoded at line 184, so it doesn't depend on target architecture, therefore it's not a problem of architecture detection :

```
xsbdynmod::
        @echo "Making XSB Shared Library $(bindir)/libxsb.$(SHAREDLIB_EXTENSION)"
        @@LD@ -o libxsb.$(SHAREDLIB_EXTENSION) $(DYNMOD_LDFLAGS)  -faltivec -fPIC $(XSBMOD_LDFLAGS)  $(OBJS) ${ODBCOBJ} ${INTERPROLOGOBJ} -lm
        @cp libxsb.$(SHAREDLIB_EXTENSION) $(bindir) 2>/dev/null || echo ""
```

You can try to remove it the configure/compile again, but you may also encounter an error suggesting you to recompile with -fPIC in order to create a shared object. Unfortunately I can't figure out where it is missing…

In fact those seem to be bugs from their build system, you should report them upstream maybe.